# Explain why the measure of irrational numbers in [0, 1] equals 1

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm having trouble understanding the how this came to be, I understand that $m([0,1]) = 1$ since the measure of an interval $[a, b] = b-a$.

Let $A$ be the set of rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and $B$ be the set of irrationals in the same interval.

It's easy to see that:
$$m([0,1]) = m(A) + m(B)$$
$$1 = m(A) + m(B)$$
Now, how do we know for sure that $m(A)= 0$?

And another problem I have is that $B$ is a subset of $R \setminus Q$ and we know $m(R \setminus Q) = 0$.

Shouldn't $m(B) < m(R \setminus Q)$?

Comment: Because 1) A measure is countable additive (that is, given a countable family $\{A_n\}$ of pairwise disjoint measurable set, then $\mu(\bigcup_nA_n)=\sum_n\mu(A_n)$) 2) $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]=\{q_k\}_k$ is a countable set, so $$\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]=\bigcup_k\{q_k\}$$ finally 3) Lebesgue measure of a point is zero (it's simply a consequence of the definition of Lebesgue measure), so $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ is the countable union of pairwise disjoint sets of null measure

Comment: $\mu(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)=0$ is wrong, it's actually $\infty$. On the other hand, $\mu(\mathbb Q)=0$. But $B\subseteq A\rightarrow\mu(B)\leqslant\mu(A)$ is right, since $\mu(B)\leqslant\mu(B)+\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(B\cup (A\setminus B))=\mu(A)$ (remember $\mu$ is positive or zero)

Answer (score 1):

The Lebesgue measure of *any* countable set of real numbers is $0$, and therefore $m\left([0,1]\cap\Bbb Q\right)=0$. It follows that $m\left([0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q\right)=1$.

Comment: I see, then what about the property of measure that a subset always have a measure less than or equal to the measure of its super set? Since m(R/Q) = 0

Comment: @AlbashirMasud But $m(R \setminus Q) \ne 0$.

Comment: @PrimeMover You mean $m(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})=\infty$

Comment: @saulspatz yes of course I did, I was confused with $[0,1]$. Corrected what I meant.

Comment: @PrimeMover note that $m\left([0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q\right)=1 \leq m\left([0,1]\right)=1$ is true since $1 \leq 1$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Yes I know, that's as obvious as a very obvious thing. Please note I wasn't the one to come up with $m(\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q) = 0$ in the first place. That's the howler made by OP which we are all trying to alert him to.